# OpenCV how to use the KalmanFilter class as ExtendedKF

Tags: c++, opencv, kalman-filter

As written in the [docs](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html?highlight=kalman%20filter#KalmanFilter), it is possible to use the cv::KalmanFilter class as an Extended-Kalman-Filter (EKF). Can someone explain me how?

All the matrices involved [are declared as public](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/video/include/opencv2/video/tracking.hpp) so I can edit all of them.
The [source code](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/video/src/kalman.cpp) is for the normal (linear) Kalman-Filter.

I think that I should edit the `transitionMatrix` with my non linear system, namely `G`.
This matrix is the one of my non linear system with as input variables both the `statePost` and the `control`; and ControlMatrix should be all 0. Right?

But where should I put the Jacobian of G?

I have the same doubt for the update process, I have my non linear system `H` for the measurementMatrix.

Maybe I'm a bit confused, can someone help me please?

Comment: I need to substitutie G and H with their Jacobians computed in the statePost right?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So, I think that I figured out how to use the `cv::KalmanFilter` class as an EKF.
This is how I made it:

1. save in a temp variable the `kf.statePost`: `temp = kf.statePost`
2. put in the `kf.transitionMatrix` the Jacobian of the transition function
3. do the prediction step of the KF
4. change the `kf.statePre` with the correct value using the transition function: `kf.statePre = f(temp, control)`
5. put in the `kf.measurementMatrix` the Jacobian of the measurement (or correction) function
6. do the correction step of the KF
7. change the `kf.temp5` matrix with the correct value: `kf.temp5 = measurement - h(statePre)` where `h()` is the measurement (or correction) function
8. change the `kf.statePost` with the correct value: `kf.statePost = kf.statePre + kf.gain * kf.temp5`

And finally you have the estimated state of the system in `kf.statePost`!

Comment: [This person](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24769194/456814) (10k+ rep users only) asks you if your 8th step should be `kf.statePost = kf.statePre + kf.gain * kf.temp5`?

Comment: @Michele - I am trying to do the same thing. Would you be me a little advice please (I don't know how to initiate "Chat" on here except to keep adding comments!

Comment: I don't think that there is a chat, can you explain your dubts?

Comment: @Michele I am not sure what f + h functions are. ALso where does temp5 come from? I sent you an email with a portion of my code to your gmail address

Comment: you can find the temp5 matrix looking at the source code of the kalman filter in the OpenCV library, the other two functions depends on the system you are estimating. Since your question about f and h is quite general (about the Kalman Filter) I suggest you to ask a new question about that. PS: I won't do the work for you for free.